# String concatenation in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell

My problem is to build a function that given a person and an amount of hours(**Integer**) it adds "erp" at the start of the name, but the "r" must multiply the amount of hours.

My function must be of the type:

```
drink :: Integer -> Client -> Client
```

here it´s an example:

```
drink 5 (Aperson name _ _) = "errrrrpname"
```

I know how to do the concatenation but i dont know how to multiply the "r" the amount of time.

Comment: Can you make a function that just takes in a `String` `s` and an integer `n` and gives back the `String` that is `s` multiplied by `n` (without dealing with the `Client` stuff)? I would start there.

Comment: Then why didn't you title your question to reflect the fact that you are interested in "string multiplication" (rather than mere "concatenation")?

Comment: If you want to use a standard library function (instead of implementing it yourself), there is `replicate`.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating a char

```
take 10 $ repeat 'a'     -- "aaaaaaaaaa"
```

Repeating a string

```
[1..10] >>= (\_ -> "x-") -- "x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-"
[1..10] >> "x-"          -- "x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-"
```

Comment: While both of these work, neither one is really appropriate for what he is doing.

Comment: @Lazersmoke I agree on that these are suboptimal, but they work, have the correct complexity, and are reasonably readable. This is a good answer in my eye, and would be very good if only the library didn't contain `replicate(M)`. But that's not a huge deal.